# Retrieve ecoinvent uuid in activity browser / brightway

Tags: brightway

Is it possible to retrieve the UUID of a ecoinvent activity in activity browser?

If not, can i access an LCA instantiated in ab through a brightway jupyter notebook to find this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: import bw2data as bd

In [2]: bd.projects.set_current("ecoinvent 3.7.1 bw2")

In [3]: ei = bd.Database("ecoinvent 3.7.1")

In [4]: a = ei.random()

In [5]: a['activity']
Out[5]: 'a9ef6142-b382-486d-ae2b-7c1b731a9efe'

In [6]: a['flow']
Out[6]: '45fbbc41-7ae9-46cc-bb31-abfa11e69de0'

In [7]: a['filename']
Out[7]: 'a9ef6142-b382-486d-ae2b-7c1b731a9efe_45fbbc41-7ae9-46cc-bb31-abfa11e69de0.spold'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! no way to do this in the Activity Browser? i'd like to have this informaton in the elementary flow contribution results, but it's a bit hard for me at the moment to replicate the same results in brightway.

Comment: I am not sure, I think might is a way to get a terminal in the AB, but you can work on the same project in iPython and the AB at the same time.